# How to choose a column of data from 2 days ago?

Tags: mysql

Currently, I am running the following SQL (in MySQL) query to return the column for records recorded at 12am on the current day, up to the current time.  So, if today is 2/3, and I run the query at 8pm, I will return all data recorded from 12:01am up to 8pm.

My question is; how do I retrieve **yesterday's** data?  I want the same column, except instead of today's date, I want yesterday.

```
SELECT column1 
FROM db.table 
WHERE TS >= CURDATE() AND TS < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

My second question is, how would I take the same column, and find the records for the entire month, up to the CURDATE()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the current WHERE condition specifies today and you want yesterday, then just subtract one day from both expressions. That will make the first expression `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` and the second simply `CURDATE()`:

```
SELECT column1 
FROM db.table 
WHERE TS >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND TS < CURDATE();
```